# Deployment Processing Phase: Error occured while pushing PagePublished data to webservice

Tags: web8, publishing, sdl-tridion, navigation

I occure the following error in the Deploying phase:

> Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed. java.lang.Exception: Error occured while pushing PagePublished data to webservice. Published Xml: tcm:261-130457

In the logs of my deployer service I can find the following:

> Cased by: java.lang.Exception: Error occured while pushing PagePUblished data to webservice. 
>   Published XML: 
>   tcm:261-130457-64
>   
>   ...
>   
>   
>   Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Connection error (is server running at http://localhost:8086/Navigation.svc/page/publish ?): java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8086

This only happens to certain pages with hold a certain page template. 
And I get the same 400 error when unpublishing.

I'm able to go to the Navigation.svc manually and when I go to the link in the error i get a 'Method not allowed' screen.

What is throwing this error and how can I fix this?

Thanks a lot,
Sybren

Comment: do you have any custom deployer?

Comment: I've setup a deployer service, under the Tridion_CD_Microservices provided by SDL if i'm not wrong.
I only changed the config files and powershell files to install the service as a windows service

Comment: This Navigation.svc is not something that comes out of the box, so it seems to be custom.

Comment: @NunoLinhares yes indeed the navigation service itself is custom. But it works for the other already existing sites, but not for the new created one.
Is it possible that this is an error cause by the page templates/schema in Tridion? Because I imported them with the content porter form an other environment.

Comment: The error states "Connection Error" - so... your error is at that service level. It might be that the extension is only triggered for specific page templates (or pages containing some sort of navigation attributes), but to debug further you'll have to look into what that service is expecting and why connection is failing.

Comment: @NunoLinhares Ok thanks for that tip! This narrows my search field.
This pages do containt a specific schema (metadata for DD4T page templates) with a view. 

Inside my logs of the service I don't see anything else then the one stated above.

Comment: It looks like we get the 400 error because of a bad request. Maybe the XML that is send is not correct.